# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentConrtroller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'studentserv';

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
    @RestController
public class StudentConrtroller {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentserv; 

                 @SuppressWarnings("null")
                @RequestMapping( "/examination")
                 public void loadAllStudent(long attendCodeId) throws IOException   {


                     StudentDto studentDto=studentserv.loadAttendancecodeId(attendCodeId);
                     if(studentDto==null ) {
                        studentDto.setCourseId(attendCodeId);
                    }
        }
}

    @Service
public interface StudentService {

    public StudentDto loadAttendancecodeId(long attendCodeId) throws IOException;


}


@Service
@Transactional
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService{

    @Autowired
    StudentDao stud;



    @Override
    public StudentDto loadAttendancecodeId(long attendCodeId) throws IOException {
        StudentDto StudentDto=new StudentDto();
        Student stu=stud.loadStudent(attendCodeId);

        if(stu !=null) {
            StudentDto.setActive(ExaminationUtil.activeInActiveStr(stu.getActive()));

            BeanUtils.copyProperties(stu, StudentDto);

        }
        return  StudentDto;}}
```

How to solve the error?????

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'studentConrtroller': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'studentserv'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'studentServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'stud'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'studentDAoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'repos'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'studentRepositor': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract
>   com.example.demo.Domain.model.Student
>   com.example.demo.StudentRepository.StudentRepositor.findByAttendExamDetaiol_Id(long)!
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at com.example.demo.SpringExaminQueryNewJoinningApplication.main(SpringExaminQueryNewJoinningApplication.java:15)
>   [classes/:na]
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'studentServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'stud'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'studentDAoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'repos'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'studentRepositor': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract
>   com.example.demo.Domain.model.Student
>   com.example.demo.StudentRepository.StudentRepositor.findByAttendExamDetaiol_Id(long)!
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         ... 19 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'studentDAoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'repos'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'studentRepositor': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract
>   com.example.demo.Domain.model.Student
>   com.example.demo.StudentRepository.StudentRepositor.findByAttendExamDetaiol_Id(long)!
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         ... 32 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'studentRepositor': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract
>   com.example.demo.Domain.model.Student
>   com.example.demo.StudentRepository.StudentRepositor.findByAttendExamDetaiol_Id(long)!
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         ... 45 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract
>   com.example.demo.Domain.model.Student
>   com.example.demo.StudentRepository.StudentRepositor.findByAttendExamDetaiol_Id(long)!
>         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:142)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:209)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:574)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:567)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:569)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:332)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         ... 55 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
>        -[IDENT] IdentNode: 's' {originalText=s}
>        [select s from com.example.demo.Domain.model.Student]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:729)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:368)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>         ... 84 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
>        -[IDENT] IdentNode: 's' {originalText=s}
>        [select s from com.example.demo.Domain.model.Student]
>         at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:118)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:78)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:158)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         ... 92 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
>        -[IDENT] IdentNode: 's' {originalText=s}
>
> ```
>   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:161)
> ```
>
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:1018)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:786)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:677)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
>         ... 98 common frames omitted`

Comment: You might want to check: [ask]

Comment: Have you actually read the stack trace? -> `Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.example.demo.Domain.model.Student com.example.demo.StudentRepository.StudentRepositor.findByAttendExamDetaiol_Id(long)!`. This quite clearly indicates your `findBy` method isn't named properly.

Answer (score 2):

As i can see @service annotation is used twice on StudentServiceImpl & StudentService.
Remove @service annotation on  StudentService interface and let it be on StudentServiceImpl.